# How to upload files to Azure Blob Storage using Azure WebJob? (Using C#, .NET)

Tags: c#, .net, file-upload, azure-blob-storage, azure-webjobs

I have a very basic understanding of Azure WebJob, that is, it can perform tasks in background. I want to upload files to Azure Blob Storage, specifically using Azure WebJob. I would like to know how to do this, from scratch. Assume that the file to be uploaded is locally available on the system in a certain folder (say C:/Users/Abc/Alpha/Beta/).

1. How and where do I define the background task that is supposed to be performed?
2. How to make sure, that whenever a new file is available in the same folder (
   C:/Users/Abc/Alpha/Beta/) the function is automatically triggered, and this new file is also transferred to Azure Blob Storage?
3. Can I monitor progress of transfer for each file? or for all files?
4. How to handle connection failures during transfer? and what other errors should I worry about?

Comment: I would recommend to read some tutorials on this topic first. If you have specific questions come back and provide some sample code of your problem

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to do the same. If you have any resources on this, please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How and where do I define the background task that is supposed to be performed?

According to your description, you could create a webjob console application in the VS.You could run this console application in the local.

More details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk#a-idworkerroleausing-the-webjobs-sdk-outside-of-webjobs) to know how to create webjob in the VS.

Notice:Sine you need watch the local side folder, this webjob is running in your local side not upload to the azure web app.

> How to make sure, that whenever a new file is available in the same folder ( C:/Users/Abc/Alpha/Beta/) the function is automatically triggered, and this new file is also transferred to Azure Blob Storage?

As far as I know, webjob support the [filetrigger](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions#filetrigger--file), it will monitor for file additions/changes to a particular directory, and triggers a job function when they occur.

More details, you could refer to below code sample:

Program.cs:

```
        static void Main()
        {
            var config = new JobHostConfiguration();
            FilesConfiguration filesConfig = new FilesConfiguration();
            //set the root path when the function to watch the folder
            filesConfig.RootPath = @"D:\";

            config.UseFiles(filesConfig);
            var host = new JobHost(config);
            // The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously
            host.RunAndBlock();
        }
```

function.cs:

```
 public static void ImportFile(
              [FileTrigger(@"fileupload\{name}", "*.*", WatcherChangeTypes.Created | WatcherChangeTypes.Changed)] Stream file,
              FileSystemEventArgs fileTrigger,
               [Blob("textblobs/{name}", FileAccess.Write)] Stream blobOutput,
              TextWriter log)
        {
            log.WriteLine(string.Format("Processed input file '{0}'!", fileTrigger.Name));

            file.CopyTo(blobOutput);

            log.WriteLine("Upload File Complete");

        }
```

> Can I monitor progress of transfer for each file? or for all files?

As far as I know, there's a [BlobInput] attribute that lets you specify a container to listen on, and it includes an efficient blob listener that will dispatch to the method when new blobs are detected. More details, you could refer to this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2014/02/18/azure-storage-bindings-part-1-blobs/).

> How to handle connection failures during transfer? and what other errors should I worry about?

You could use try catch to catch the error.If the error happens you could send the details to the queue or write a txt file in the blob. Then you could do some operation according to the queue message or the blob txt file.